# database on php only server

Tags: php, database

I am trying to create a site with a tiny CMS, the problem is that there is only php installed on the server.

The site will mainly consit of two pages the user page and admin page. On the user page there is to be a bunch of checkboxes which when checked will do some math(not the problem I need solved). On the admin page you need to be able to add the checkboxes and assing them their values.

My approach was to read and write to a XML file that contains the data instead of a database. I have run into a lot of problems trying to accomplish this, and I am looking for some good ideas for how it can be done, or alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. Be specific about the problems you have had with XML. As it stands this question is off-topic for [so]

Comment: hard to find a host with out mysql. but then SQLite is always an option

Comment: xml or config file is the best approach for this problem, and I do not see any problems with it, so you need to ask another question(s) about particular problems

Comment: There are CMSs available which use xml rather than a database GetSimpleCMS is an example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as database engine. This way you also create a portable version of your application and by using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you could always switch to another database engine later on.